# Div and its content are moving

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in this div and its content. When I resize the window, it shifts horizontally left or right.

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <div class="over_1">
    <span><a href="#">1.1<br/>TROUT</a></span>
    <span class="fish"> <img src="images/fish.png" /></span>
    <span class="fve"> <span>5</span></span>

</div>
```

And here is the CSS code I am using:

```
.over_1 {
position: relative;
width: 170 px;
top: -340px;
height: 175px;
float: left;
border-radius: 1000px;
left: 42%;
text-align: center;
}
```

I want the image and the text to stay in the center regardless of the windows size.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: you want image and text in center or whole div to be in center on window

Comment: Please create a fiddle for better understanding

Comment: Don't use float.

Comment: @Chilll007 The div contains an image and some text, I want everything to stay in its place while resizing the windows.

Comment: if you want it in center remove the float and left property instead use margin: 0 auto; which will make div to horizontal center of your window. if you want any changes https://jsfiddle.net/LoL10m82/4/ edit this fiddle or create new one here so we can see what you exactly want.

Answer (score 0):

what happen if you remove:
left:42%;
float: left;

and you add:
width: 100%

is the result is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
float: left;
left: 42%;
```

Add

```
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
```

`display:table` is required to get it working in IE8+